# android supported devices

Tags: android

i developed one application that should run on all the android supported devices.can you please suggest me different screen resolution of android os devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QVGA-L
QVGS-P
HVGA-P
HVGA-L

were the original standard resolutions.

WQVGA (DSTL1 etc)
WVGA (Droid Incredible)
1366 * 768 WXGA (ODROID T)

are all the ones since developed that I'm aware of at the moment. generally android applications should run in portraid & landscape (and sometimes square) orientations.

There doesn't seem to be a central place where all this information is posted, but if you use QVGA/HVGA and scalar settings for larger resolutions this may get help for future devices.